# Fetch Promise gets blocked by Chrome's Cache

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to use the Fetch API with promises, and I have the following call to an API.

```
export const refreshTokenAPI = () => {
  return fetch('/api/auth/gettoken/' ,{
    cache: 'no-store',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic '+ btoa(getToken() + ':'),
      'pragma': 'no-cache',
      'cache-control': 'no-cache'
   }
  })
    .then(response => {
      return handle_response(response)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw error;
    })
};
```

When I try to call this, the response just sits as 'Pending' and doesn't go anywhere from there. The weird thing is that when I disable the cache from inside the dev console, it resolves just fine. As you can see from the snippet, I've tried a bunch of things to disable the cache from the call itself, but none of them do anything.

I've even tried old-school cache busting on the endpoint itself, so I'm completely at a loss! Any thoughts?

EDIT: It turns out that if you wait for long enough (~40seconds), it does eventually resolve with the cache enabled... no idea why the cache would cause it to hang so badly?

Comment: Aren't you missing a step before calling `handle_reponse(response)` ? First return the `json` (`return response.json()`) from response and later handle the result.

Comment: handle response contains `return response.json()` itself:
`const handle_response = (response) => {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  }
  throw response
};
` 
That being I could always try calling it first?

Comment: where is the next `.then()` stage to handle the result of `handle_response`? I mean `response.json()`.

Comment: Just tried moving `return response.json()` to where it normally lives, and you get the same effect: works fine if the cache is disabled, but hangs forever otherwise :(

Comment: Can you try with all addons disabled? Mostly this could be an addon issue.

Comment: @Redu I probably am misunderstanding the purpose of the second 'then', but because the first one returns what I (think) i need, I never included it. I just tried adding a trivial one in: `.then((everything) =>  (everything))
    })' and it hasn't changed anything. I don't know if that's to be expected or not..?

Comment: @Panther all chrome extensions are off. Also tested in incognito which incidentally worked fine. Clearing all browser data doesn't help though. Also, (unsurprisingly perhaps) it turns out that the port is blocked while the promise is stuck - tried getting in through another browser window and couldn't load anything

Comment: `response.json()` returns another promise and when you return it in the next (second) `.then()` stage you access the data object. Such as `fetch('https://randomuser.me/api').then(res => res.json()).then(userData => console.log(userData));`

Comment: hmmm thanks @Redu, I thought as much. Unfortunately it doesn't change the weird caching behaviour though :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution, and it's actually on the backend, and appears to have little to do with the Cache.

I'm using Python/Flask as the router, and by allowing threading (`app.run(debug=True, threaded=True, port=5000)`), the problem goes away. I have no idea why this would be the case, but there you have it.

I actually bit a minimal flask application that reproduces the problem. It only requires python 3 and Flask to run. It's on [github here](https://github.com/enjeyw/Flask-Promise-Bug), but here's the code:

Application.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify

application = Flask(__name__)


@application.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@application.route('/foo/', methods = ['GET'])
def get_foo():
    return jsonify({'message': 'bar'}), 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # application.run(threaded = True) # This works
    application.run()                # This doesn't
```

/templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
Loaded...
</body>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log('document ready');

  fetch('/foo/').then(function(response) {
    console.log('then triggered');
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(json) {
   console.log(json)
  });
});
</script>

</html>
```

Hard to believe that something so standard could not work!